# Remove modules from recompiled vmlinux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I was trying to remove extra modules of from kernel to reduce its size. The selection of modules I am doing through make menuconfig command. But the final installed kernel is loading and screen is black? What to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

First, modules are, by definition, not part of the kernel binary.
They're standalone binary file, usually installed under `/lib/module/<uname -r>/` so removing their support won't make kernel binary lighter.

Current symptom (blank screen) is too broad to help you.

I would advice you to proceed step by step: given a working kernel configuration, remove set of options by set of options and test. Iterate until the resulting kernel stop working or you reach the targetted size.